# Different APN Device Token ID for same application

Tags: swift, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just followed the tutorial of http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1  for creating a sample push notification example....

But I dono where I went wrong I am receiving **different token ID** on different devices for the same application.

Here is my code for reference,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications();

        return true
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        println("My token is \(deviceToken)")  // am getting it different for different devices
    }

    //Called if unable to register for APNS.
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

        println(error)

    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        println("Recived: \(userInfo)")
        //Parsing userinfo:
        var temp : NSDictionary = userInfo
        if let info = userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        {
            var alertMsg = info["alert"] as! String
            var alert: UIAlertView!
            alert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: alertMsg, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
```

One more problem is that I am receiving a sound and banner but not **"badge"**

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: you will get different for each device, this is expected .

Comment: Oh! Then if I have a server and I dont know how many people have downloaded my app from the app store...in that case how will i send notification to all ??

Comment: You have to incorporate this thing in your design (server), you will send user's device ID to server and send push as needed

Comment: Do u know how to communicate with the server..based on this tutorial ??If yes can u explain me.

Answer (score 1):

In your "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken"
send your device Token to server like this

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let deviceTokenStr = HDDataLayer.convertDeviceTokenToStr(deviceToken)
    HDDataLayer.postNotificationServiceResponseByUrlString("pushnotifications/notifications/register", andParams: tempDict, andDictCompletion: { (response: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("Device Register successfully")
    })
}
```

Please Note that HDDataLayer is my own class and you will use class you are using to interact with your server.